# Temporarily Disable Firefox Sync

Tags: sync, firefox, firefox-extensions

In Firefox 4, is there a way to temporarily disconnect from Sync? You can do this with the add-on for version 3.x, but it doesn't seemt o be an option for version 4.

Answer (score 2):

Via http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/795646

> connect/disconnect was intentionally
>   removed. Sync is meant to just be
>   there and "connects" when needed.

Which I think is silly.

Comment: Agreed. Especially when you want to make large changes to your bookmarks and (re)organize them. Every change gets synced as you make it. Guess it's load on the Sync server, so not "my" problem :)